# jQuery DataTable responsive doesnt work with Boostrap 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I am having problems with responsive layout when i use DataTable js plugin. It wont show it even if there is responsive: true. I tried to manipulate with css (white-space: nowrap) but that isnt solution. Here is the preview of code.

HTML

```
    <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="no-sort"></th>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Product Category</th>
            <th>Views</th>
            <th>Average View Time</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="text-center">1</td>
            <td>Accu-Pass Suture Shuttle</td>
            <td>Suture Shuttle</td>
            <td>1,500 views</td>
            <td>8:38 minutes</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

JS

```
$('#example1').DataTable({
      responsive: true,
      columnDefs: [
          { targets: 'no-sort', orderable: false }
        ],
      "paging": true,
      "lengthChange": true,
      "searching": true,
      "ordering": true,
      "info": false,
      "autoWidth": true,

    });
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7mj5LLno/)

Comment: In your fiddle you don't load jquery and datatable plugin.

Comment: There is jquery and datatables js and css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Fiddle example, you are missing the Jquery and datatable plugin.

**Fiddle Example with Jquery and Datable plugin**: 
https://jsfiddle.net/n2vbzn8g/2/

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example1').DataTable( {
        responsive: true,
              columnDefs: [
          { targets: 'no-sort', orderable: false }
        ],
      "paging": false,
      "lengthChange": true,
      "searching": false,
      "ordering": false,
      "info": false,
      "autoWidth": true
    } );
} );
```

**Table**

```
<table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="no-sort"></th>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th>Product Category</th>
        <th>Views</th>
        <th>Average View Time</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="text-center">1</td>
        <td>Accu-Pass Suture Shuttle</td>
        <td>Suture Shuttle</td>
        <td>1,500 views</td>
        <td>8:38 minutes</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```